# Java выдает ошибку exit code=1

Tags: java, eclipse

Здравствуйте. Когда, в eclipse indigo, делаю синхронизацию проекта с svn (плагин Subclipse), то выкидывает ошибку:

[image]

Вот файл eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Вот файл hs_err_pid6800.log из папки eclips

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000007fee8bc362c, pid=6800, tid=7028
#
# JRE version: 7.0_01-b08
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (21.1-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsvn_subr-1.dll+0x1362c]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000000a44c800):  JavaThread "Worker-7" [_thread_in_native, id=7028, stack(0x000000000ebc0000,0x000000000ecc0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x000000000fab427d, RCX=0xffffffffffffffff, RDX=0x000000000fab427d
RSP=0x000000000ecbd950, RBP=0x000000000fab427d, RSI=0x000000000f1ecac8, RDI=0x0000000000000000
R8 =0x000000000fab4168, R9 =0x000000000fab4168, R10=0x0000000000000007, R11=0x000000000fab426c
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x000000000fab4168, R14=0x000000000fab2208, R15=0x0000000000000000
RIP=0x000007fee8bc362c, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000000ecbd950)
0x000000000ecbd950:   000000000fab01f8 000000000fab2238
0x000000000ecbd960:   000000000fab2238 000000000fab2208
0x000000000ecbd970:   000000000fab2238 000007feea66f32b
0x000000000ecbd980:   000000000fab427d 000000000fab41f0
0x000000000ecbd990:   000000000f1ecac8 0000000000000000
0x000000000ecbd9a0:   0000000000000000 00000000ffffffff
0x000000000ecbd9b0:   000000000f1ecf28 000007feea66f4c9
0x000000000ecbd9c0:   000000000fab2238 000000000fab4168
0x000000000ecbd9d0:   000000000fab2228 000007fee8bb1c01
0x000000000ecbd9e0:   000000000fab41e0 000007feef3d1f21
0x000000000ecbd9f0:   000000000f1ef058 000000000fab2228
0x000000000ecbda00:   000000000fab21d0 000007fee8bb1c01
0x000000000ecbda10:   000000000fab4168 000000000fab41e8
0x000000000ecbda20:   000007fee8b6d548 00000000ffffffff
0x000000000ecbda30:   000000000cf4fd70 000007fee8adf794
0x000000000ecbda40:   000000000f1ef058 0000000000000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x000007fee8bc362c)
0x000007fee8bc360c:   74 24 18 48 89 7c 24 20 41 54 48 83 ec 20 4c 8b
0x000007fee8bc361c:   e1 48 83 c9 ff 33 c0 49 8b fc 4d 8b c8 48 8b ea
0x000007fee8bc362c:   f2 ae 48 8b fa 48 f7 d1 48 8d 71 ff 48 83 c9 ff
0x000007fee8bc363c:   f2 ae 48 f7 d1 48 ff c9 48 8b d9 48 85 f6 75 0f 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x000000000fab427d is an unknown value
RCX=0xffffffffffffffff is an unknown value
RDX=0x000000000fab427d is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000000ecbd950 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000000a44c800
RBP=0x000000000fab427d is an unknown value
RSI=0x000000000f1ecac8 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R8 =0x000000000fab4168 is an unknown value
R9 =0x000000000fab4168 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000007 is an unknown value
R11=0x000000000fab426c is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x000000000fab4168 is an unknown value
R14=0x000000000fab2208 is an unknown value
R15=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x000000000ebc0000,0x000000000ecc0000],  sp=0x000000000ecbd950,  free space=1014k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libsvn_subr-1.dll+0x1362c]  svn_relpath_join+0x2c

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.apache.subversion.javahl.SVNClient.status(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/subversion/javahl/types/Depth;ZZZZLjava/util/Collection;Lorg/apache/subversion/javahl/callback/StatusCallback;)V+0
j  org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.javahl.AbstractJhlClientAdapter.getStatus(Ljava/io/File;ZZZZLorg/tigris/subversion/svnclientadapter/ISVNStatusCallback;)[Lorg/tigris/subversion/svnclientadapter/ISVNStatus;+135
j  org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.client.StatusCommand.execute(Lorg/tigris/subversion/svnclientadapter/ISVNClientAdapter;Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)V+67
j  org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.client.StatusAndInfoCommand.execute(Lorg/tigris/subversion/svnclientadapter/ISVNClientAdapter;Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)V+3
j  org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.client.StatusAndInfoCommand.run(Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)V+12
j  org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.sync.SVNWorkspaceSubscriber.findChanges(Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IResource;ILorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)[Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IResource;+95
j  org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.sync.SVNWorkspaceSubscriber.refresh(Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IResource;ILorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IStatus;+43
j  org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.sync.SVNWorkspaceSubscriber.refresh([Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IResource;ILorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)V+91
j  org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.synchronize.RefreshSubscriberParticipantJob.doRefresh(Lorg/eclipse/team/internal/ui/synchronize/RefreshParticipantJob$IChangeDescription;Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)V+24
j  org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.synchronize.RefreshParticipantJob.run(Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IStatus;+183
j  org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run()V+31
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000008e27800 JavaThread "Worker-13" [_thread_blocked, id=7112, stack(0x0000000012110000,0x0000000012210000)]
  0x000000000a452800 JavaThread "Worker-12" [_thread_blocked, id=7104, stack(0x0000000011f70000,0x0000000012070000)]
  0x000000000a451000 JavaThread "Worker-11" [_thread_blocked, id=7096, stack(0x0000000010bf0000,0x0000000010cf0000)]
  0x000000000a44b000 JavaThread "Worker-10" [_thread_blocked, id=7092, stack(0x0000000011d70000,0x0000000011e70000)]
  0x000000000a450000 JavaThread "Device List Monitor" [_thread_in_native, id=7084, stack(0x00000000100f0000,0x00000000101f0000)]
  0x000000000a44e000 JavaThread "Worker-9" [_thread_blocked, id=7040, stack(0x000000000ae10000,0x000000000af10000)]
  0x000000000a44d800 JavaThread "Worker-8" [_thread_blocked, id=7036, stack(0x000000000abc0000,0x000000000acc0000)]
=>0x000000000a44c800 JavaThread "Worker-7" [_thread_in_native, id=7028, stack(0x000000000ebc0000,0x000000000ecc0000)]
  0x000000000a44a800 JavaThread "Worker-6" [_thread_blocked, id=7024, stack(0x000000000e610000,0x000000000e710000)]
  0x000000000a449800 JavaThread "Worker-5" [_thread_blocked, id=7020, stack(0x000000000e980000,0x000000000ea80000)]
  0x000000000a449000 JavaThread "Worker-4" [_thread_blocked, id=6992, stack(0x000000000e500000,0x000000000e600000)]
  0x000000000a44c000 JavaThread "Worker-3" [_thread_blocked, id=6988, stack(0x000000000be10000,0x000000000bf10000)]
  0x000000000a448000 JavaThread "Worker-2" [_thread_blocked, id=6984, stack(0x000000000e320000,0x000000000e420000)]
  0x000000000a444000 JavaThread "Monitor" [_thread_in_native, id=6980, stack(0x000000000e140000,0x000000000e240000)]
  0x000000000a447000 JavaThread "Worker-1" [_thread_blocked, id=6968, stack(0x000000000df50000,0x000000000e050000)]
  0x000000000a446000 JavaThread "Bundle File Closer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6964, stack(0x000000000de20000,0x000000000df20000)]
  0x000000000a444800 JavaThread "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6960, stack(0x000000000dc10000,0x000000000dd10000)]
  0x000000000a2bd000 JavaThread "Java indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6952, stack(0x000000000dd10000,0x000000000de10000)]
  0x0000000009ea2800 JavaThread "Worker-0" [_thread_blocked, id=6920, stack(0x000000000bc80000,0x000000000bd80000)]
  0x0000000007909000 JavaThread "Worker-JM" [_thread_blocked, id=6892, stack(0x000000000b620000,0x000000000b720000)]
  0x000000000999a800 JavaThread "[Timer] - Main Queue Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6888, stack(0x000000000b410000,0x000000000b510000)]
  0x00000000091ae800 JavaThread "Framework Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6880, stack(0x000000000a860000,0x000000000a960000)]
  0x0000000008afd000 JavaThread "Start Level Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6876, stack(0x00000000093f0000,0x00000000094f0000)]
  0x0000000008b36000 JavaThread "State Data Manager" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6872, stack(0x00000000095a0000,0x00000000096a0000)]
  0x0000000008b45000 JavaThread "Framework Active Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=6868, stack(0x00000000092e0000,0x00000000093e0000)]
  0x000000000651e000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6856, stack(0x0000000006f70000,0x0000000007070000)]
  0x000000000651b800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6852, stack(0x0000000007520000,0x0000000007620000)]
  0x0000000006516800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6848, stack(0x0000000007400000,0x0000000007500000)]
  0x0000000006510800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6844, stack(0x0000000007250000,0x0000000007350000)]
  0x000000000650b000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6840, stack(0x00000000070f0000,0x00000000071f0000)]
  0x0000000002884000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6836, stack(0x0000000006e20000,0x0000000006f20000)]
  0x000000000287a000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6832, stack(0x0000000006cd0000,0x0000000006dd0000)]
  0x000000000278b800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=6808, stack(0x0000000002a00000,0x0000000002b00000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000002875800 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000006b50000,0x0000000006c50000] [id=6828]
  0x000000000652f000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000007630000,0x0000000007730000] [id=6860]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 133824K, used 45248K [0x00000000f5560000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 96768K, 20% used [0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000f6927cd8,0x00000000fb3e0000)
  from space 37056K, 67% used [0x00000000fdbd0000,0x00000000ff438490,0x0000000100000000)
  to   space 38976K, 0% used [0x00000000fb3e0000,0x00000000fb3e0000,0x00000000fd9f0000)
 PSOldGen        total 113792K, used 85245K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e6f20000, 0x00000000f5560000)
  object space 113792K, 74% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e533f400,0x00000000e6f20000)
 PSPermGen       total 129856K, used 90967K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d7ed0000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 129856K, 70% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d58d5f50,0x00000000d7ed0000)

Code Cache  [0x0000000002b00000, 0x00000000030c0000, 0x0000000005b00000)
 total_blobs=2297 nmethods=1499 adapters=747 free_code_cache=43418Kb largest_free_block=44348224

Dynamic libraries:
0x000000013fa90000 - 0x000000013fac3000     C:\Windows\system32\javaw.exe
0x0000000077320000 - 0x00000000774c9000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000076da0000 - 0x0000000076ebf000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefda40000 - 0x000007fefdaac000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x0000000074b90000 - 0x0000000074bcf000     C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\snxhk64.dll
0x000007fefe590000 - 0x000007fefe66b000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007feff590000 - 0x000007feff62f000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007fefdf30000 - 0x000007fefdf4f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007fefe460000 - 0x000007fefe58d000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x0000000077220000 - 0x000000007731a000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007fefdbd0000 - 0x000007fefdc37000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007fefe670000 - 0x000007fefe67e000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007fefe680000 - 0x000007fefe749000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007fefc0a0000 - 0x000007fefc294000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_fa396087175ac9ac\COMCTL32.dll
0x000007fefe780000 - 0x000007fefe7f1000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007fefe750000 - 0x000007fefe77e000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007fefde20000 - 0x000007fefdf29000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x000007fefd6a0000 - 0x000007fefd6df000     C:\Windows\system32\nvinitx.dll
0x000000000f000000 - 0x000000000f006000     C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\CoProcManager\_etoured.dll
0x000007fefa170000 - 0x000007fefa1b5000     C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\CoProcManager\nvd3d9wrapx.dll
0x000007fefe1c0000 - 0x000007fefe397000     C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x000007fefd9e0000 - 0x000007fefda16000     C:\Windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll
0x000007fefdd40000 - 0x000007fefde17000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x000007fefdfb0000 - 0x000007fefe1b3000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x000007fefda20000 - 0x000007fefda3a000     C:\Windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x000007fefa120000 - 0x000007fefa162000     C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\CoProcManager\nvdxgiwrapx.dll
0x00000000708e0000 - 0x00000000709b1000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x0000000063ff0000 - 0x00000000646bd000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007fef3e90000 - 0x000007fef3e99000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x000007fefdf50000 - 0x000007fefdf9d000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007fefdfa0000 - 0x000007fefdfa8000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fefb3c0000 - 0x000007fefb3fb000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x00000000774f0000 - 0x00000000774f7000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x0000000070a90000 - 0x0000000070a9f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000070a60000 - 0x0000000070a88000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.dll
0x0000000070a40000 - 0x0000000070a55000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\zip.dll
0x000007fefd010000 - 0x000007fefd027000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x000007fefcd10000 - 0x000007fefcd57000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x000007fefca80000 - 0x000007fefca9e000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x000007fefd6e0000 - 0x000007fefd6ef000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x000007fefd670000 - 0x000007fefd67f000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x0000000070a20000 - 0x0000000070a39000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\net.dll
0x000007fefcfb0000 - 0x000007fefd005000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x000007fefcfa0000 - 0x000007fefcfa7000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x000007fefbac0000 - 0x000007fefbad5000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x000007fef5930000 - 0x000007fef5945000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x000007fef5910000 - 0x000007fef5929000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x000007fefce30000 - 0x000007fefce8b000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x000007fef5900000 - 0x000007fef590b000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x000007fef5790000 - 0x000007fef57a0000     C:\Windows\system32\wshbth.dll
0x0000000073ff0000 - 0x000000007401e000     C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live\WLIDNSP.DLL
0x000007fefc8e0000 - 0x000007fefc8e7000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x000007fefb830000 - 0x000007fefb857000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x000007fefb820000 - 0x000007fefb82b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x000007fef5780000 - 0x000007fef5788000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x000007fefb6e0000 - 0x000007fefb733000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x0000000070a00000 - 0x0000000070a11000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\nio.dll
0x0000000072000000 - 0x0000000072012000     C:\Games\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502\eclipse_1406.dll
0x000007fefc810000 - 0x000007fefc81c000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x000007fefbd00000 - 0x000007fefbd56000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x0000000010000000 - 0x00000000100a7000     C:\Games\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\595\1\.cp\swt-win32-3738.dll
0x000007fefdca0000 - 0x000007fefdd37000     C:\Windows\system32\comdlg32.dll
0x000007fefe800000 - 0x000007feff588000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x000007fef9bf0000 - 0x000007fef9c61000     C:\Windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x0000000076c40000 - 0x0000000076d9a000     C:\Windows\system32\WININET.dll
0x00000000774e0000 - 0x00000000774e3000     C:\Windows\system32\Normaliz.dll
0x0000000076ec0000 - 0x00000000770cf000     C:\Windows\system32\iertutil.dll
0x00000000770d0000 - 0x000000007721d000     C:\Windows\system32\urlmon.dll
0x000007fefd830000 - 0x000007fefd997000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x000007fefd820000 - 0x000007fefd82f000     C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x000007fefc9f0000 - 0x000007fefca08000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x000007fefbed0000 - 0x000007fefbffc000     C:\Windows\system32\propsys.dll
0x000007fefe3a0000 - 0x000007fefe439000     C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x000007fef96e0000 - 0x000007fef96ec000     C:\Windows\system32\LINKINFO.dll
0x00000000029a0000 - 0x00000000029be000     C:\Games\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\595\1\.cp\swt-gdip-win32-3738.dll
0x000007fefbae0000 - 0x000007fefbcf5000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7601.17514_none_2b24536c71ed437a\gdiplus.dll
0x000007fefb100000 - 0x000007fefb22a000     C:\Windows\system32\WindowsCodecs.dll
0x0000000180000000 - 0x0000000180011000     C:\Games\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\72\1\.cp\os\win32\x86_64\localfile_1_0_0.dll
0x000007fefa970000 - 0x000007fefa9c4000     C:\Windows\system32\oleacc.dll
0x000007fef91d0000 - 0x000007fef939a000     C:\Windows\system32\explorerframe.dll
0x000007fefb4c0000 - 0x000007fefb503000     C:\Windows\system32\DUser.dll
0x000007fefb900000 - 0x000007fefb9f2000     C:\Windows\system32\DUI70.dll
0x000007fef26d0000 - 0x000007fef26e1000     C:\Games\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\75\1\.cp\jWinHttp-1.0.0.dll
0x000007fef4c00000 - 0x000007fef4c71000     C:\Windows\system32\WINHTTP.dll
0x000007fef4b90000 - 0x000007fef4bf4000     C:\Windows\system32\webio.dll
0x000007fefb550000 - 0x000007fefb568000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x000007fefb530000 - 0x000007fefb541000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x00000000709d0000 - 0x00000000709f4000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\sunec.dll
0x000007fefd680000 - 0x000007fefd694000     C:\Windows\system32\RpcRtRemote.dll
0x000007fef47d0000 - 0x000007fef480b000     C:\Windows\system32\mlang.dll
0x000007fefa1c0000 - 0x000007fefa1c7000     C:\Windows\system32\msimg32.dll
0x000007fefd610000 - 0x000007fefd667000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x000007fefc640000 - 0x000007fefc66d000     C:\Windows\system32\ntmarta.dll
0x000007fefdc40000 - 0x000007fefdc92000     C:\Windows\system32\WLDAP32.dll
0x000007fef6d90000 - 0x000007fef6e10000     C:\Windows\system32\ntshrui.dll
0x000007fefd370000 - 0x000007fefd393000     C:\Windows\system32\srvcli.dll
0x000007fef6d80000 - 0x000007fef6d8f000     C:\Windows\system32\cscapi.dll
0x000007fefba70000 - 0x000007fefba7b000     C:\Windows\system32\slc.dll
0x00000000719e0000 - 0x00000000719f0000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseStub.dll
0x0000000071960000 - 0x00000000719db000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseSVN.dll
0x000007fef89e0000 - 0x000007fef8dab000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\libsvn_tsvn.dll
0x0000000071930000 - 0x000000007195b000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\libapr_tsvn.dll
0x00000000718e0000 - 0x0000000071921000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\libaprutil_tsvn.dll
0x000007fef89d0000 - 0x000007fef89e0000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\intl3_tsvn.dll
0x000007fef89b0000 - 0x000007fef89ca000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\libsasl.dll
0x000007fefd410000 - 0x000007fefd41b000     C:\Windows\system32\Secur32.dll
0x000007fefd5e0000 - 0x000007fefd605000     C:\Windows\system32\SSPICLI.DLL
0x0000000070c30000 - 0x0000000070cc8000     C:\Windows\system32\MSVCP100.dll
0x000007fefab70000 - 0x000007fefab7c000     C:\Windows\system32\netutils.dll
0x000007fef73e0000 - 0x000007fef73fd000     C:\Windows\system32\mssprxy.dll
0x0000000070800000 - 0x00000000708d1000     C:\Games\eclipse\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win64_1.7.2\MSVCR100.DLL
0x0000000070760000 - 0x00000000707f8000     C:\Games\eclipse\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win64_1.7.2\MSVCP100.DLL
0x0000000070730000 - 0x000000007075a000     C:\Games\eclipse\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win64_1.7.2\libapr-1.dll
0x00000000709c0000 - 0x00000000709cd000     C:\Games\eclipse\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win64_1.7.2\libapriconv-1.dll
0x000007feea3f0000 - 0x000007feea574000     C:\Games\eclipse\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win64_1.7.2\libeay32.dll
0x000007fef2680000 - 0x000007fef26ce000     C:\Games\eclipse\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win64_1.7.2\ssleay32.dll
0x000000006f450000 - 0x000000006f488000     C:\Games\eclipse\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win64_1.7.2\libaprutil-1.dll
0x000007fef6c40000 - 0x000007fef6d65000     C:\Windows\System32\dbghelp.dll
0x000007fefabb0000 - 0x000007fefabcb000     C:\Games\eclipse\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win64_1.7.2\libsasl.dll
0x000007fee8bb0000 - 0x000007fee8d17000     C:\Games\eclipse\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win64_1.7.2\libsvn_subr-1.dll
0x000007fef7420000 - 0x000007fef7427000     C:\Windows\system32\SHFOLDER.dll
0x000007feef3d0000 - 0x000007feef3f7000     C:\Games\eclipse\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win64_1.7.2\libsvn_delta-1.dll
0x000007fef2660000 - 0x000007fef267d000     C:\Games\eclipse\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win64_1.7.2\libsvn_diff-1.dll
0x000007feea640000 - 0x000007feea6ec000     C:\Games\eclipse\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win64_1.7.2\libsvn_wc-1.dll
0x000007feef160000 - 0x000007feef1a0000     C:\Games\eclipse\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win64_1.7.2\libsvn_fs-1.dll
0x000007feebb70000 - 0x000007feebbae000     C:\Games\eclipse\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win64_1.7.2\libsvn_repos-1.dll
0x000007fee8ad0000 - 0x000007fee8ba9000     C:\Games\eclipse\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win64_1.7.2\libsvn_ra-1.dll
0x000007feea7b0000 - 0x000007feea81e000     C:\Games\eclipse\plugins\org.tigris.subversion.clientadapter.javahl.win64_1.7.2\libsvn_client-1.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5 -Xms40m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m 
java_command: C:\Games\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -showsplash -launcher C:\Games\eclipse\eclipse.exe -name Eclipse --launcher.library C:\Games\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502\eclipse_1406.dll -startup C:\Games\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar --launcher.overrideVmargs -exitdata 1a88_a4 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -vm C:\Windows\system32\javaw.exe -vmargs -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5 -Xms40m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -jar C:\Games\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.7.0-Q16;C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\PROGRA~2\Borland\CBUILD~1\Bin;C:\PROGRA~2\Borland\CBUILD~1\Projects\Bpl;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\12.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Roxio\OEM\AudioCore\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
USERNAME=Igor
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 42 stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, ht

Memory: 4k page, physical 8280236k(4763796k free), swap 16558624k(12456452k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (21.1-b02) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_01-b08), built on Oct  3 2011 01:39:25 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Sun Feb 26 18:38:45 2012
elapsed time: 26 seconds
```

Google именно на эту ошибку (exit code=1) никаких ответов не дал. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить?

Comment: Гуглить нужно не на это.
А на: 'A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment' libsvn_subr-1.dll

Попробуйте создать чистый проект.

Comment: Погуглил, посмотрел, почти всё что предлагается сделать, я сделал ещё до того как сюда написал, всё кроме пере установки eclipse.
Проекты создаются, запускаются и всё тому подобное. Этот проект удалил, попытался сделать chekout, выскочила эта же ошибка.

Comment: Так у вас ошибка как раз в либе svn, с помощью которой вы делаете checkout

Comment: хорошо, тогда подскажите, как мне её исправить или хотя бы направьте на ресурс, где это объясняется?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогла переустановка IDE и Android SDK.